# Tools to compress and encrypt files

Tags: security, encryption, compression

I want to **compress** several files and **encrypt** them with a password if possible.

- Are there any **build-in tools** in Mac OS that provide such functionality?
- If not, can you recommend me a (freeware) alternative?
- I'd also be happy with a terminal command.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, you can do this using the [built-in Disk Images of Mac OS X](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Disk_Image). A disk image (or DMG file) is a file which, when opened, presents itself as a removable Mac OS X volume, similar to a removable hard drive. Many OS X applications are deployed on disk images. If you encrypt your home directory using FileVault, you're creating a spare bundle disk image.

You can create OS X disk images which are compressed and/or encrypted.  However, if you create a *compressed* DMG, it will be read-only, so that may or may not work for you.

To create a new, empty encrypted disk image in OS X:

1. Open **Disk Utility**, which is under the "utilities" folder of the "Applications" folder.
2. From the **File** menu choose **New > Blank Disk Image...**
3. In the dialog that appears, you can specify where to save the disk image, the name of the volume, and choose the type of encryption:

[image: New Disk Image Dialog]

- Make sure to choose either "128-bit AES encryption (recommended)" or "256-bit AES encryption (more secure)" from the "Encryption" menu. Also, be sure to set a size for the disk image.
- If you create a sparse bundle (newer, and may be more reliable) or a spare image (older, can become corrupted easily if it's open and your computer is shut down improperly) then the image file will start small and will grow as you add files to it, up to a maximum size you specify.
- If you create a "read/write disk image", then the image file will start at the maximum size specified in the dialog box.

After you save the disk image file, you'll be prompted for a password and verification. Once completed, you'll have a new volume on your desktop and in the "Computer" view where you can begin dropping files!

[image: Final result]

**To create a compressed, read-only image**, you can do one of two things:

1. Follow the same steps above, however instead of **New > Blank Disk Image...**, choose **New > Disk Image From Folder...**. This will first ask you to select a folder full of files. From there, it will present a similar dialog to the one above, but will not prompt for a volume name or size; it will use the name of the folder and the size will be automatically calculated. **Be sure to choose to make a compressed image and don't forget the encryption**

   [image: Imaging a folder]
2. Alternatively, if you have created a blank image and filled it with files, you can convert that image to a compressed image. **This is a handy way to back up your encrypted files.** Keep the master read/write uncompressed image as your day-to-day workspace, and periodically convert it to a read-only compressed image which you can back up to an external device. To do this, choose **Images > Convert...** within Disk Utility. Select the DMG file, and then you'll see the same screen as above.

**Protip:** if you *drag and drop a folder onto Disk Utility's dock icon* it will automatically offer to create a disk image out of that folder.

**Protip #2:** If you create an encrypted disk image out of an unencrypted folder and you want to delete the original, unencrypted files, **remember to use secure erase** otherwise you risk leaving confidential information on your hard drive.

Comment: +1 Excellent instructions.  I have an addition to protip #2, though: usually previous versions of the files will have been deleted insecurely (most programs do this when saving changes), so it's best to securely erase the free space on the disk afterward (run Disk Utility, select the volume in the sidebar, then the Erase tab, then click Erase Free Space.  When it asks how thorough to be, select the basic "Zero Out" mode).

Comment: Thank you very much! Indeed very helpful, especially with the Protips. It is fast. What I like best, is that the **password** I created is **stored in the keychain automatically.**

Comment: While storing the password for an encrypted image in the Keychain is convenient, it's also something of a security risk because anyone who gains access to your account also has access to the DMG file. Consider using a password container like Password Wallet or 1Password instead. Or create a separate keychain file, using a second password, to contain your dmg passwords. This keychain file can be locked and unlocked separately from the login keychain.

Comment: Great points @jaberg. I also recommend keeping multiple keychains, one for everyday stuff and one for more secure items.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way to compress is to just right-click any file and select the appropriate option to create a zip file (without password though).

On command-line/Terminal level there are at least

- `zip` which supports encryption (`zip -P password ...`)
- `gzip` which doesn't
- `openssl` which only encrypts (so compress with `gzip` first), e.g. `openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -e -in note.txt -out note.txt.enc -pass pass:money`

For zip and openssl the password will be visible to all users while the encryption is running. This is usually not a problem on a desktop system, otherwise you may consult the `openssl` man page for ways to read the password from a file or similar.

Comment: `zip`'s encryption is inherently **unsafe**; the encryption can be broken with freely available tools. Not recommended. (Some more details: `zip`, shipped with macOS, is actually the _Info-zip_ utility, http://www.info-zip.org, from 2008. For compression, it uses the `zlib` library, also shipped with macOS. `zlib` however doesn't support encryption; the encryption is done by _Info-zip_ - in a (somewhat) PKZIP-compatible way.)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with just tools in OSX

For simple compression right click on the file in Finder and choose compress..

To compress and add a password - With Disk Utility create a new disk image - choosing the Encryption and Image format options. Then copy the files into it.

From the command line look at gzip and zip

Answer (score 0):

Though I recommend and use encrypted DMG files myself-see [Josh](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/1521/josh)'s [accepted answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/32775/11791)–there is an alternative way to do this in Terminal using a combination of free and built-in tools.

[Jason](https://stackoverflow.com/users/26860/jason) Seney explains in his article [Open, Edit & Save Encrypted Files with Vim and GPG](http://jasonseney.com/post/18646147210/open-edit-save-encrypted-files-with-vim-and-gpg):

> Using vim and gpg we can open, edit, and save only the encrypted file and leave nothing in plain text on the hard drive.

Using [MacGP2](http://www.gpgtools.org/macgpg2/index.html) you can encrypt:

```
gpg -c -o myfile.mkdn
```

and decrypt:

```
gpg -d myfile.mkdn.gpg
```

Jason's  article provides instructions to pipe files directly in and out of vim and the *secret sauce* for creating alias commands that make encrypting and decrypting easy.

As I said, I make use of the built-in DMG tools, but if you're a command line user, particularly of vim, or if you need to insure that plaintext copies of your secret files never exist on disk or in swap files, Jason's method is worth considering.

Comment: It's worth re-iterating that decrypting the file and then writing the decrypted data to the hard drive is dangerous (as in the `gpg` example in this answer). It is difficult (almost impossible with some drives) to definitively erase the unencrypted file. If you're serious about security use an encrypted dmg - it is the only secure option. You can create encrypted dmg's from the command line using the `diskutil` command line tool (it offers everything in Disk Utility.app and more). In recent versions of OS X, swap is always encrypted unless you disable it (hard to do).