# Backing up individual files with encryption

Tags: macos, backup, command-line

In addition to local Time Machine backups, I would like to automatically backup my working data  from my Macbook to a remote FTP space. Because it's  a location I don't control and sensitive data, I want to use encryption.

There are some approaches floating around the 'net how to achieve this, for example [this tutorial](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20070925155109846) that uses `duplicity` and works great (I've tested it).

However, all these approaches generate file archives of some sort (`tar`s in the latter example). I would like to have a  backup where I can access **every file individually, but encrypted.** So the backup structure would look something like this:

```
 Work
  Documents
     Letter to Mr.T.doc.encrypted
     Expenses.txt.encrypted
  Images
     Sunshine.jpg.encrypted
```

does anybody know a tool that can achieve this?

Alternatively, is there a stand-alone OS X command that can encrypt files? I might be able to use that in combination with `rsync` to build this on my own.

Comment: These don't directly solve the issue as you'd like, but here are the methods I've used: #1 - Create an encrypted disc image. Mount it and drop the files you'd like to backup into it. Have some utility to sync this remotely (I use SugarSync). #2 - Use CrashPlan [free year membership here] (https://www.crashplan.com/carboniteswitcher/) to backup to their encrypted cloud. In CrashPlan settings you can create a custom 448-bit encryption key to encrypt the backup.

Answer (score 2):

This question is a subset of: [Tools to compress and encrypt files](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/32730/tools-to-compress-and-encrypt-files/)

See answer here:  https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/32732/43002 for built-in command line utilities which (with some scripting) will do what you want. (Such as `zip -P` and `open-ssl`)