# Looking for Encryption application

Tags: macos, applications, windows, software-recommendation, encryption

I want to encrypt a file then email it. The recipient needs to decrypt it.  Needs to be free.

I'm looking for an encryption application that runs on Windows 10 and macOS 10.10 at a minimum.  Would be nice if the app run on android, ios, macOS and Windows.  All I want is to have the application: Ask one question, provide file, then encrypt file.

Actually, it doesn't have to be the same app, but multiple apps that encrypt and decrypt in the same format.

Does Windows have encryption?  Could I find an app that mimics the windows encryption?

What I don't want is for the app to ask a lot of questions like what type of encryption I want,how to save the output file, save a bunch of files on my drive, no command line stuff, easy to hack file, etc.

Comment: Are the Mac(s) and PCs all yours? Both Platforms provide disk encryption, so are you trying to secure the files when they are transmitted between them? Some more detail of your use case might help.

Comment: See also https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/32730/tools-to-compress-and-encrypt-files

Answer (score 1):

<sub><sub>[image]</sub></sub> [**Encrypto**](https://macpaw.com/encrypto) by MacPaw is a free file encryption app available for macOS and Windows. The app uses AES-256 with no configuration; provide a password for encryption and optional password hint.

> [image]

Answer (score 1):

Save the file to iCloud and then send the person a link to download it?

I'm not a fan of cross platform encryption tools due to the friction to set them up properly and choose them, but you could do far worse than trying signal.

- https://www.signal.org

Other notable options in the space are https://gpgtools.org and https://www.openpgp.org

But seriously, try the simplest thing that could work - iCloud - and then see if the others are worth the setup.

Comment: I'd mention underpass in passing, since it's awesome and peer to peer, but you need to be on macOS or iOS only for that to work: https://underpassapp.com

Answer (score 1):

Consider [Firefox Send](https://send.firefox.com/):

> Firefox Send lets you share files with end-to-end encryption and a link that automatically expires.

For files up to 1Gb you don't need to sign up.